# R changes symbols inside column names when reading csv

Tags: r, csv, format

I have a dataframe where each column name specifies the City, Type of bank account, Year it was open, and if it's Active or not.

The first four column names would look something like this:

[image]

However, when I upload this data into R with a `read.csv` function, the `|` values convert to `.`, and in fact the first column name will look something like:
`Barcelona.Standard.2012.True`, etc.

Why is this happening? And how can I fix it?

In summary, every column name is separated by a `,` and has several `|` inside.

Comment: Not clear about `I want to highligh that the | symbol is inside the column name`.  If I understand your question, you have the first row i.e. column names have `sep` as `,` and the rest of the rows with `|`.  Probably you can read them separately with `skip = 1` without column names and read the column names alone with `readLines` `n = 1`

Comment: Hi @akrun. Thanks for the answer, but not really, I updated the question as it was generating some misunderstandings

Comment: Your image didn't show any column names

Comment: By default, `read.csv` (any most other reading functions commonly used) checks that column names are syntactically valid, and fixes them if they aren't. The ones you have aren't. Verify this by trying to assign a value to a variable called `x|2012`. If you *really* want to use invalid names, set `check.names = FALSE`, and then you'll have to refer to column names in backticks

Comment: Why do you want the information about those four different variables to be encoded in the column names? That is not a good format regardless of whether the separation character is `.` or `|` because it will make it very difficult to manipulate the data in R.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what you mean, but if your data is in a text file that looks like your excerpt and you want to load it into R with `read.csv()` this will get you what you want, I think:

```
read.csv(
  file = "data.txt", 
  sep = "|", 
  header = FALSE, 
  col.names = c("city", "type", "year_opened", "active"),
  colClasses = c("active" = "logical")
) 

       city     type year_opened active
1 Barcelona Standard        2012   TRUE
2    Berlin      One        2013   TRUE
3    London      One        2014   TRUE
4 Barcelona Standard        2015   TRUE
5    Berlin      One        2016   TRUE
```

Comment: Hi @rdelrossi. Thanks for the answer, but not really, I updated the question as it was generating some misunderstandings

Comment: When you say, "I have a dataframe," I presume you mean something other than R data.frame, such as a spreadsheet? Could you post an excerpt of the document you're trying to read with `read.csv()`?